# get string of entire new element's HTML without adding it to the page

Tags: jquery

```
var div = $('<div/>').text('inner text');
```

I want the full html of the div element including the element itself, not just the text inside it.

How can I do that?

```
div.get(0) // gives me an HTML Element Object, which I'm not sure what to do with.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get(0)` will give you an object, use **[`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)** property on it.

```
div.get(0).outerHTML
```

or

```
div.prop('outerHTML')
```

---

```js
var div = $('<div/>').text('inner text');
alert(div.get(0).outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```